Replacement for Prunus x Cistena
I've had a Prunus Cistena in my garden for 10 years -- flowered gloriously in the spring, but added interest all year due to its leaf colour.
Last year it exhibited cherry leaf scorch; this year it didn't flower and is indeed dead as the proverbial dodo.
What can I replace it with that does the same job? Profuse white/pink flowers in spring, red/purple leaves, height and spread around 1 metre, fairly sheltered positon close to a fence. I'm in the UK, Gloucestershire/Wiltshire border.  Don't think I should plant another cherry :(

How sure are you the problem was Cherry Leaf Scorch - this problem doesn't  usually affect P. Cistena. Could it have been fireblight, which would be a good reason not to plant any member of the Rosaceae family in its place?

@Bamboo Curled scorched looking leaves that didn't drop. No exudate, no apparent damage to bark or underlying wood by inspection. A nearby crab apple (Malus Sylvestris) wasn't affected. The prunus blossomed heavily last year, then the leaves curled and died. This year there was no leaf growth nor any blossom.

These are short lived plants, usually around 10 years, so if you planted it ten years or more ago, that might be why its died. The symptoms you describe could be fireblight though, and if it was, then any member of the Rosaceae family will be vulnerable there.
The problem is, there isn't really a replacement that will do the job you're looking for in terms of profuse flowering, size, and purple leaves. You could consider one of the Berberis atropurpureum group, which will at least give you the purple leaves during spring/summer, Choose a smaller variety, or at least check height and spread before buying.  Otherwise, Physocarpus 'Diabolo' would be an option, but it is in the Rosaceae family, so may be susceptible if there was a problem with fireblight. It also gets taller and wider than Prunus cistena...

Thanks.
I already have Physocarpus Diablo in the same section of garden (so far without problems) as well as roses close to where the cherry died.  We'll see...  I'll have a look at Berberis.

I forgot to say that any purple/red leaved Berberis will need plenty of sun,  otherwise it will just be plain green...

Not a problem in the planned position. Unless we enter FimbulWinter...
